# How to create unique constraints in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How do I create unique constraints using laravel 5.2 Schema Builder?

```
Schema::create('my_pivot', function(Blueprint $table){

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('table1_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('table2_id')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('table1_id')->references('id')->on('table1');
    $table->foreign('table2_id')->references('id')->on('table2');

    //Here i need to add an unique constraint to 'key1' + 'key2'

});
```

Comment: $table->unique(['key1', 'key2']);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass an array to the `unique` method.

```
$table->unique(['key1', 'key2']);
```

Documented under *Available Index Types* in the [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#creating-indexes)